# Is there a way to find out the error code when Samsung refrigerator "Fridge off" led is blinking and fridge is working

Tags: refrigerator

I am trying to figure out if the refrigerator requires service or just  combination of button presses to reset it.
This is 4.5 years old Samsung rt18m6215sg refrigerator. Few days ago the control panel on the refrigerator lights turned off and I only see constant blinking "Fridge Off" led.  I've tried to restart it via fuse box and power cable.  I also tried to press different combination of buttons and only was able to change it into Sabbath Mode and then turned it off.  Which means I think buttons are working.  I also tried to take the food out and turn off the refrigerator for 24 hours and when turned back on the led is just blinking.  The weird part is that the refrigerator is working and cooling.  I have a thermometer that shows 40F in the fridge and freezing temp in the freezer.  I've spoke to Samsung support and they weren't able to help me.  I've searched online for a while but couldn't find a service manual or error code information.  I don't think this is Cooling off mode as the refrigerator operating normally.  Does anyone have any ideas if the blinking LED means some error code? I am going to call the service department but I am thinking this issue can be resolved with some sort of reset.

Thank you in advance!

This is the picture of the control panel inside the freezer with "Fridge Off" led blinking

**Update:**.

Spoke to the technician in the store which we purchased the refrigerator from and he said that most likely the issue is the control board and requires replacement but I am still hopeful that I can reset it as the cooling does work

**Update 2:**

Kept the refrigerator on after the 24 hour reset, freezer and fridge temp is normal.  Tested with fridge thermometer.
I am still hoping there is a way to reset the control panel as the compressor works normally

[image: Samsung refrigerator rt18m6215sg control panel]

Comment: I'd like to thank this and the many other questions about whacky Samsung appliance behaviors and failure modes for warning me off ever buying a Samsung appliance. Samsung's own support can't help you... Good luck!

Comment: @Ecnerwal Haha .. Thanks!

Comment: Your fridge has a "Sabbath Mode"? Are you in Israel? Does it shut down at sunset on Friday and power back up at sunset on Saturday when in Sabbath Mode?

Comment: @FreeMan I am in the US.  Didn't know about it until I pressed the button combination thinking it was to reset but as it turns out was Sabbath mode. From the manual: `The Sabbath mode stays active for 85 hours once it is activated. After that, it will be deactivated automatically.`.  After activating lights turned off but refrigerator was still working

Comment: That is... odd... I may have to go do some searching to figure out what Sabbath mode is.

Comment: [Sabbath Mode](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00062340/). I'd guess that a blinking light is not part of Sabbath mode.

Comment: I don't think so.  Sabbath mode is to make sure the lights are not turned on when opening the door.

Comment: @FreeMan Sabbath Mode is not just for Israel. Many Jews strictly observe Shabbat, regardless of location. There are quite a few buildings in NYC with elevators on Sabbath Mode, long before we ever heard of Samsung

Comment: I guess if it's still working that's a good sign :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://support-cacyber.samsung.com/cacyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=878967&modelcode=RF32FMQDBSR/AA), it looks like the refrigerator defrost sensor might be bad. What I'm not sure of is if you're seeing an error code or just a malfunction of the panel.

**To get the error codes, use this procedure:**

Hold the round Freezer and Fridge buttons for 10-15 seconds

[image]

...which should cause the display lights to blink. Cross-reference the blinking light with the chart(s) below.

[image]

[image][image]

Here is the [full tech support website](https://support-cacyber.samsung.com/cacyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?lang=ca&idx=85609&modelname=&modelcode=RF32FMQDBSR/AA&session_id=NBgK3JZW6nPIaWvHU78Zvko3kqvib-oxNtU-v8Okhl_8ys7YqIE0!910825134!1685349087!1645154702934). You may find some information in it which will help you further. It does caution, in several places, not to reset the error codes as not having them makes troubleshooting much harder for a service technician. The ship may have sailed on that.

If you need it, here is the [Owner's Manual](https://manualsfile.com/download/ln6tcg9t8.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I wish I found this site before I turned off the fridge for 24 hours.  I am guessing I've erased all the history.  Nothing happens when I try to press freezer/fridge buttons.   Still blinking.  I wonder if one of the buttons are broken

Comment: I do not know. You did hold the buttons for 10-15 seconds, right?

Comment: I did hold it many times .. will have to get serviced next week .. hopefully issue with def sensor wouldn't kill the refrigerator before then

Comment: I suspect that, if the defrost sensor is the problem, you might be good for a while maybe. As long as it takes for frost to build up? I don't know. Might keep an eye on that.

Comment: Might make sense.  We left the refrigerator door open a bit on few occasions and I think this happened after it was open for a bit